# Is there a standard name for a flanged threaded tube?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fasteners

I have designed a custom part that I need, but it is so simple I'm sure there must be off-the-shelf versions available. However I don't know what it's called to search for it.

[image: Threaded tube with flange at one end]
[image: Flanged nut thing]

The image on the left is the custom part I designed, it's basically a short threaded tube with a flange at one end. The tube is 10mm long and 8mm outer diameter, with an M7x0.75 thread. Note that although it's quite dark inside the tube in the picture and difficult to see, the tube is open at both ends.

The image on the right is a kind of flanged nut type thing I found in a leather strap binding, it's similar to what I need only smaller and also too short, so I know I'm not the only person to want a part like this.

I have searched for "flanged nut", and "threaded insert", among other terms, but I can't seem to find anything like this. Is it a thing? What's it called?

Answer (score 4):

I've always referred to this style of female fastener as a "T-Nut"

Comment: Where I'm from, a T-nut would be one where the flange has teeth on the outside for biting into wood. There are also weld nuts which are a similar shape, for welding the flange to a base metal.

Comment: For me a T-Nut is what you use to fasten into a slot in aluminium profile. It goes in sideways then rotates to hook under the slot as you tighten it.

Comment: Those are all things commonly called T nuts. The term T nut is also used to refer to the nuts used for workpiece holding in the slots on a machine bed, such as a mill.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of different parts that are similar to this. If you found it binding a leather book together, it was probably paired with a male threaded fastener with a matching head. If so, the pair would be called either a 'binding post' or a 'sex bolt.' They come in many different sizes and materials.

Comment: My part is similar to the 'sex bolt' or 'barrel nut' (thanks, not heard the name of those before either), but I need the hole to go all the way through.

Comment: Hmmm interesting. Does the outside have to be round? McMaster Carr has some metric flange nuts if you can use a hex outside shape, although M7 might be too exotic of a thread. See if 91005A035 is close to what you want.

Comment: It doesn't need to be round, but it needs to fit through an 8mm round hole in a panel and fasten around an M7 male thread, so there's not much thickness available to make it not round. It's for securing a rotary encoder to a front panel so that the PCB that the encoder is fixed to doesn't flex back when you press the button. The shaft of the encoder comes through the hole, which is why it needs to be open.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, Search google for "threaded tube bung" or "threaded bung" you can find all sorts of sizes/styles and threads. They are typically used in conjunction with tube-type fabrication/weldments.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a known problem.  Some people use similar for potentiometers on older gear when cases were thicker and penny pinching was not essential.

Below is a part that might fit and may be a stock item somewhere.  I searched for *potentiometer nut thick panel* in Google image search. I have seen similar made of brass with round rim with two slots for a hollow wrench.

EDIT: *The Caption for this picture was **Note unusual "deep threaded" nut!** so it is unusual even when encountered in the field.*

http://www.abalonevintage.com/1960s_Gibson_EMS-1235_guitar_pot_shaft.jpg

I would try and find a suitable clinch nut from some vendor, check the pictures in this image search for most likely candidate.  Thread pitch may limit choices. Some types do not have the thread all the way through even if the hole does go as they are riveted into place. The collapsing types have the benefit of usually a thin wall design.

https://www.google.com/search?q=clinch+nut&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMI1LHj5-3byAIVygcsCh0zhgRL&biw=1400&bih=778

Some similar items are called a furniture connector in some places.

http://www.ap-magazine.com/upload/fastener/Product/Image1/Screw35439m95925.jpg

http://i01.i.aliimg.com/photo/v0/908973835/Custom_stainless_steel_carbon_steel_M6_M8.jpg

Comment: Perhaps some products from PEM Fasteners or similar could work. ---- http://www.pemnet.com/fastening-products/standoffs/